# Windsor Castle resolving multiple dependencies with same interface

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor

Problem:

Class constructor is as below:

```
public class ParsingRulesProvider : IParsingRulesProvider{
    public ParsingRulesProvider(List<IParsingRule> rules){}
}
```

We have two rules:

```
public class ARule : IParsingRule{
    public ARule(IASomeObject someObject){}
}

public class BRule : IParsingRule{
    public BRule(IBSomeObject someObject){}
}
```

Questions:

How to register in code:

1. `ParsingRulesProvider` with rule A and B?
2. `ParsingRulesProvider` with all objects implementing IParsingRule?
3. `ARule` and `BRule`?

Answer (score 0):

AD1)

```
container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new ListResolver(container.Kernel, true));
```

AD2)

```
container.Register(Component
    .For<IParsingRulesProvider>()
    .ImplementedBy<ParsingRulesProvider>());
```

AD3)

```
    container.Register(Component
            .For<IParsingRule>()
            .ImplementedBy<ARule>()
            .LifeStyle.Singleton
            .Named("ARule"));

    container.Register(Component
        .For<IParsingRule>()
        .ImplementedBy<BRule>()
        .LifeStyle.Singleton
        .Named("BRule"));
```

Comment: Please include English words in your answer describing the code and how it answers the question. I see three Registers but no way to resolve a particular component.